# Protecting data in Multi User web applications

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, web

I have a big problem in my mind at the moment. To make a long story short, lets take some kind of online pharmacy network as an example. It has millions of users, millions of data but one single database. Lets assume that database has a `Patient` table. Every new patient added by every new pharmacy will be saved in this table.

However, even though data are in the same `Patient` table, it makes sure pharmacy "A" can only access its patients and not anyone else, pharmacy "B" can only access its patients but not anyone else and so on. They will provide a user name and password for every single pharmacy but again, since there is only on `Patient` table and only one database, how they make sure these data are not being shared with each other? I am sure they don't create separate databases for every single user :D

**Update**

Please don't confuse with my question. As `TonyHopkinson` said, using the `PharmacyID` in `Patient` table is the solution. Yes, but how to do we ensure more security ? If some one uses the "Pharmacy A" profile and managed to get into the database, he has all the information including other pharmacy data as well, right?

Comment: Put PharmacyID in the Patient table and use it to restrict what patient records can be selected is the simplistic answer. You might want to do a basic database course/tutorial, definitely made a mountain out of a mole hill, here.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: Thanks for the reply, this is how large scale applications like Facebook does it too?

Comment: This is not really a scaling question. Scaling should be transparent. So you might split the db by say country, but then you would be splitting both patients and pharmacies. If I needed to scale the db by partitioning tables, I wouldn't use mysql I'd use a dbms designed to scale, which mysql is not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring to the association concept (as in UML). A patient may be tied to one or multiple pharmacies, and a pharmacy has one or multiple patients. This is related to the database conception.